# Window.addEventListener not working on Chrome

Tags: tampermonkey, userscripts

I have the following userscript which I am trying to run on Chrome and on Firefox.  I am getting inconsistent results. The script is matched (the alert fires) but on Chrome the addEventListener does not appear to work. On Firefox, it runs although there is still a problem of some kind with the insertion of the modified .js which I have yet to figure out. FWIW, my ultimate objective is to add port labeling functionality to an Ethernet switch which would be cool if I could get it to work. This script is just meant to see if I can modify the .js file that the switch runs as part of its web GUI.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Test
// @match       http://192.168.3.21/System.html
// @description TEST
// @version     1
// @grant       GM_xmlhttpRequest
// @run-at      document-start
// ==/UserScript==

function addScript(text) {
    //text = text.replace(/Normal/g, "Abnormal");
    alert(text);
    var newScript = document.createElement('script');
    newScript.type = "text/javascript";
    newScript.textContent = text;
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    head.appendChild(newScript);
}

window.addEventListener('beforescriptexecute', function(e) {
    var src = e.target.src;
    if (src.search(/system_data\.js/) != -1) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        GM_xmlhttpRequest({
            method: "GET",
            url: e.target.src,
            onload: function(response) {
                addScript(response.responseText);
            }

        });
    }
});
```

Comment: beforescriptexecute is not supported in Chrome. Check out [these topics](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=beforescriptexecute).

Comment: Thanks. I am looking for a way to have the script work on FF, Chrome, Safari, and iOS. I've looked at at most of these posts and I've yet to find the "recipe" for modifying a js function before it executes or in this case, before the js code containing the variable values is used.